# How to use GCDAsyncSocket and imported GCDAsyncSocket.framework in swift？

Tags: ios, swift, asyncsocket, gcdasyncsocket

I want to use GCDAsyncSocket in swift when build the project show this error

```
 Use of unresolved identifier 'GCDAsyncSocket'
```

my code is

```
self.socket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue())
```

I try add this to my Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "GCDAsyncSocket.h" // for TCP
#import "GCDAsyncUdpSocket.h" // for UDP
```

The above problems are solved but new problem

```
'GCDAsyncSocket.h' file not found
```

**somebody say need to imported GCDAsyncSocket.framework
how to import this？**

Comment: a while back i used it in a project of mine, i just added the `GCDAsyncSocket.m and .h` files to my project and then put `#import "GCDAsyncSocket.h"` in the bridging header, maybe make sure the file is under your compile sources in your projects build phases?

Comment: Where can find GCDAsyncSocket.m and .h, Can you give me a link or some advice？

Comment: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/tree/master/Source/GCD

Comment: thank you so much!